# SQL Server - find the person(s) that are each in all of the specified groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @person_groups table (person_id int NOT NULL, group_id int NOT NULL)
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1000, 501) --sample data
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1001, 501) --sample data
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1001, 502) --sample data
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1001, 503) --sample data
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1002, 502) --sample data
insert into @person_groups(person_id, group_id) values (1002, 503) --sample data

declare @tempGroupList table (group_id int)
insert into @tempGroupList(group_id) values (501) --sample data
insert into @tempGroupList(group_id) values (502) --sample data
insert into @tempGroupList(group_id) values (503) --sample data
```

I need to find the person ids in table @person_groups who are each in every group listed in @tempGroupList

pseudo code for a group list of 501, 502, 503,... :

```
SELECT person_id 
FROM   @person_groups 
WHERE  person_id is a member of group #501 
and that same person is also a member of group #502
   and that same person is also a member of group #503) 
   and so on for each group id contained in @tempGroupList)
```

I am currently doing this with a cursor (yucky, I know). I am trying to refactor this on MS SQL Server (up to 2012) to not use a cursor (nor dynamic sql) but am having some trouble..

Can anyone shed some light on a good solution?

Comment: You are looking for the "INNER JOIN" and "GROUP" commands. look them up.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    g.person_id
from
    @person_groups g
        inner join
    @tempGroupList l
        on g.group_id = l.group_id
group by
    g.person_id
having
    count(distinct g.group_id) = (select count(*) from @tempGroupList);
```

To explain slightly. The `inner join` restricts us to just the groups in question. The `group by` allows us to calculate the number of different (distinct) groups each person is in.  The `having` filters down to the people in the right number of distinct groups.

If a person can only appear once in each group (i.e. `group_id, person_id` is a unique combination in `@person_groups`) then you don't need the `distinct`.